Read tables from PBI semantic models and write data to Warehouse in Fabric
Can we read a table from a PBI semantic model in Microsoft Fabric using PySpark notebook and write it to a warehouse?
I am able to perform the above operation to a lakehouse but unable to do so with warehouse. Please let me know how to proceed.
I have used pyspark code in notebook for lakehouse. Below is the code. I want the same for warehouse.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("LakehouseIntegration") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read data from the Lakehouse
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM pbi.`Financials_Test`.`financials`")

# Write the DataFrame to the Lakehouse
df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("delta") \
    .option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name") \
    .option("delta.minReaderVersion", "2") \
    .option("delta.minWriterVersion", "5") \
    .saveAsTable("Fin")


Where is your data Wearhouse present and provide the error which you are getting?

my warehouse is present in the same workspace in fabric.
Error: AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Spark SQL queries are only possible in the context of a lakehouse. Please attach a lakehouse to proceed.)

Writing to Warehouse directly from Spark is on the roadmap.  But if you write to a lakehouse in the same workspace, you can read the table from the warehouse using a 3-part name, eg
select * from MyLakehouse.dbo.MyTable
